# What kind of education would telekinetic children get in a modern country?

Tags: alternate-history, super-powers, military, mind, power-scaling

In this case I'm assuming a low level telekinetics that can do anything they can see. People with Telekinetic skills are not discriminated against too much but they make up a small portion of the population e.g. (1 in 2149 to 1 in 15787 like [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)) depending on who you ask.

1. You are born a Telekinetic but improving your skills takes time and effort
2. A typical telekinetic who's done some "light training" from their manfiestation can only use their powers within withing 0.572 meters around them and can only hold up a mass of 572 grams
3. The most powerful, but official, and well training telekinetic users (i.e. the ones who go through years of intensive mental training, diet and enhancements) are able to use their powers within a hundred meters and control or crush anything up to a 100 kilogram in weight.
4. Being telekinetic very calorie intensive. Using their powers requires taking high energy drinks and telekinetic that regularly use their powers eat 2.8 times more than someone who would otherwise do so
5. The most widely believed theories as to why telekinetics are being born now is due to a greater understanding on material forces of the universe and a "passive" effect of more widespread technology. Humans are evolving in conjunction with technology and this is the first step to a new type of humans. People believed that that our brains grew bigger with the invention of fire and the invention of industrial technology has shown the rise of telekinetics here.
6. Telekinetic users have no limits to manipulating objects so long they can perceive them, under the weight limit and in range of them. This includes binding, telekinetic fields, levitation, crushing, force or etc.
7. Telekinetic users can manipulate anything they can see, touch, hear or understand i.e. they can remove or destroy the wiring of a tank if they know where it is
8. There are telekinetic enhancements but with "modern" technology there is not way to block a telekinetic from doing their works. Since this is a fundamental force it can't be stopped
9. Horrible experimental camps have been noted to increase the powers of telepaths with some success (e.g. the range of these telekinetics are between 1 to 10 kilometers and able to move or effect anything from 1 ton to less than 10 tons) but the survival and usable rates here are 6.25% and 0.390625% respectively. This is because unlike official methods which don't have any problems if you know what you are doing these methods kill people. You also have to torture young children and spend years or potentially decades actively doing to get results.
10. Telekinetic users have only started appearing in the past few generations (i.e. since the end of the second world war).

Altogether I've made such changes or limits because I'm trying to make a butterfly net so to speak. However I am interested and curious to know how such telekinetics would effect the the wider world by just existing and how wars would go.

Given this how would a developed nation train or teach their newly telekinetic children?

Comment: One question per post please, and with a narrow scope, answerable in a measurable way.

Comment: @L.Dutch "in a measurable way", mm quite an improvement on stances. 2OP no matter how detailed u define the abilities, outcome of your question can be any, at best it is what-if scenario.  Ability is so much ovepowering that it is story builbing question, u trough story tell us what do u think will happen, we may not like it and write  a different story, but all in all it about what we do or do not like. Used right the feature is stronger than nuke, and safer to use, so we could be on venus terraforming it already or play mad max for real - every possibility is equally possible.

Comment: I see u on fantasy se as well, so do they not accept such questions there? Looks like it could be a question for them, when one could unleash his fantasy. Setting is interesting, and a lot can be done with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Medicine - especially cardiovascular system

Could you give the artery leading to that brain tumor a little *twist*?  Thanks!  (They might want to train up their range an extra yard or two so they can stand outside the MRI machine looking at the monitor)  Could you yank the clot a little bit backward in the artery of this stroke patient so some blood gets past?  This lady has a retinal tear - look through the opthalmoscope and see if you can tuck it back together while we laser it.

### Firefighters

Training up telekinetic firefighters is, yes, awesome.  With the right terahertz and radar imaging equipment, you can pull people out of harm's way *without* taking the time to go in first.  That said, mishaps involving flying them through fire or leaving pieces behind in sharp debris would probably limit overall acceptance of the program.

### Science

Get them decent imaging equipment and they can physically push things around inside experimental electronic elements or control the precise angle between two sheets of graphene.  If the force limit is overall rather than per object, then they could use the skill to compress tiny samples more than a diamond anvil.  The ability to disassemble unseen wiring seems to imply sensory capacity, which may be even *more* important in their ability to contribute to research projects.

### Assassination

The medical skills seem well suited to causing brain bleeds, painful neuralgia, paralysis, etc.  If the force limit mentioned above does not apply, their ability could grip a small piece of flesh and push it into or through a victim like a sharp knife.  There would need to be some technical obstacles in the way, I think, to be consistent with the premise of public acceptance.  Perhaps the assassin *glows* during the act, in which case the ability is little more useful than an ordinary firearm for the well trained, or a knife for the novice.

Overall, I think the number needing extra strength, like firefighters, would be much less than the number doing medicine or other light uses.